# Пункты меню по всей ширине

Tags: вёрстка

Есть следующая [структура](http://jsfiddle.net/DCkws/), нужно сделать так чтобы все пункты меню растягивались максимально, то есть если даже будет 1 пункт меню он должен занимать в данном случае всю серую область, есть у кого какие идеи как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот такой чит применить:

html:

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ссылка 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">я тут один</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.menu {
    display: table;
    width: 400px;
}
.menu ul {
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: table-row;

}

.menu ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #3a3;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/b9ZBD/) - тут еще объяснение чем это лучше таблицы (можно использовать разные

```
@media screen *-width {

}
```

Comment: круто. спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

можно с помощью javascript устанавливать ширину элемента по формуле: ширина области/кол-во элементов